# How do you generate a JWT for authentication with google API using a service accout?

Tags: google-api, jwt, service-accounts

I have tried many methods of generating a JWT for the google API using the private key downloaded when I created my service account. All of the methods I have tried have errored saying the signature is invalid. I have gone through the documentation on google and do not know what I am missing. I am hoping someone has a simple working implementation of this that I can use for a reference.

Additional information:

I would like to implement this in Unity3D using C#.  The API that I am attempting to connect to is "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token".

Comment: What language are you using I have examples in a number of languages.   Also which api you are trying to connect to.  Please edit your question and include [example] and the full error message.

Comment: @DaImTo I added a little more information to the question.  The full error message is just "Invalid signature", as I have tried on multiple websites to just get a JWT generated for testing purposes before trying to actually do it programmatically.

Comment: The  [Google .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client) doesn't support Unity3d authorization.   But you may be able to use it for service account auth.   try to dig around in the code or try and install the auth part,  I dont know enough about Unity3d to help more.

Comment: @DaImTo what languages do you have working examples in?  I may still be able to work with it to meet my needs, even if I can't use it directly within Unity.

Comment: All i have is standard C# using the client library.    It doesnt support Unity either.   Every few years I try again to work out service account authorization manually I always end up going back to the library.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have for standard C#?

Comment: Which api are you connecting to?  I may be able to find something basic.  [Drive service account](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)  I offer a consulting service if this is something you want me to help you with my contacts are in my profile.